# How to create bump map using as little RAM as possible?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, numpy-ndarray, bump-mapping

I am working with Python and NumPy. I have an image:

[image]

Its heightmap:

[image]

I want to combine them to create a [bump map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_mapping) like:

[image]

I need to use as little RAM as possible. The formula is:

```
newColor = oldColor+(tint-oldColor)*abs(difference)*k
```

`difference` is the difference in value between 2 adjacent points. `tint` is zero if `difference` is negative and 255 when `difference` is positive. `K` is 0.5. Basically a pixel lighter if the slope faces north, and darker if the slope faces south. I am allocating too many ndarrays, using too much ram. Is there a way of doing it with fewer arrays?

`image` is a NumPy `ndarray(shape=(8192,3192,3),dtype=np.uint8)`. `heightmap` is a NumPy `ndarray(shape=(8192,3192),dtype=np.float32)` with values from 0 to 255. My code:

```
#Store the difference in height between two adjacent points
deltas = np.roll(heightmap,1,0)
np.subtract(heightmap,deltas,out=deltas)
difference = np.repeat(deltas[:,:,np.newaxis],3,axis=2)
del deltas

#newColor = oldColor+(shade-oldColor)*difference*k
shades = np.where(difference>0,np.int16(0),np.int16(255))
np.absolute(difference,out=difference)
np.multiply(difference,K,out=difference)
np.subtract(shades,image,out=shades)
np.multiply(difference,shades,out=difference)
del shades
np.add(image,difference,out=image,casting='unsafe')
del difference

#Save image
preview = I.fromarray(np.flip(image,0))
preview.save('image.png')
```

Comment: Perhaps if you explain using this reference you can get a quicker answer https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Normal-Mapping